search and filters is not working for autoGroupColumnDef
I am using adaptable grid tree data view for displaying data -
gridOptions = {
        autoGroupColumnDef = {
        "field": "name",
        "headerName": "Financial Statement",
        "width": 200,
        "pinned": "left",
        "filter": "agSetColumnFilter"
        floatingFilter: false,
        cellRendererParams: {
          suppressCount: true,
        }
      }
        treeData: true, // enable Tree Data mode
        getDataPath: data => {
          return data.name
        },
        getRowStyle: (params) => {
          if (params.data.class==='level1') {
            return { background: '#d7d8e9' };
          }
        },
      }



For the first column i.e., 'Financial Statement', I do not provide colDef as I'm giving autoGroupColDef.
rest of the columns are provided as colDefs.
attaching screenshot of Search and Filter of adaptable grid with red pen-


Now when I select 'filters' btn from the right side of panel all columns are listed but this "Financial Statement" column is not listed.
And similarly when I try to search, search is applied on all numeric columns but not on "Financial Statement" column.


I want these searcha nd filter feature to work on autoGroupColumnDef as well. Is there something Im missing or doing wrong?
I am using adaptable grid version 17.0.6 ag-grid version 30.2.1
